# comparison of QNX , Linux, Windows CE in terms of security

Tags: linux, qnx, windows-embedded-compact

Can somebody help me in knowing which of the os(**QNX,WINCE,LINUX**) is best in terms of security and why ?

Comment: Impossible to give an answer without a clear definition of "best" (measured/determined how?), "security" (network?), and a specification that documents how these operating systems were configured (e.g. Windows CE is highly componentized; is the network stack included? the HTTP server?)

Comment: @AshwanthSelvam Interesting topic but could you elaborate a little bit more one the use case you've got in mind. "Security" is just a too broad term to discuss meaningfully. Keep in mind those OSs* you've mentioned are quite different with different emphasis on certain (embedded) features.
*(ignoring that the term "Linux" refers to a kernel rather than an OS)